# $\oint_C\text{Re}(z)dz$ is independent of the path $C$ between $z_0 = 0$ and $z_1 = 1+i$.

Tags: complex-analysis, contour-integration, complex-integration

[My way to prove that](https://i.stack.imgur.com/w26gc.png)$\oint_C\text{Re}(z)dz$  is independent of the path $C$ between $z_0 = 0$ and $z_1 = 1+i$.
This statement is false. I tried to take $z(t)=t+it$   and then I found this;
  $\oint_C〖(t+it)dt〗=(1/2)(t^2/2+it^2/2)$ 
But I couldn't keep move. How can I prove this statement is false? What should I do to keep moving?
If I take another $z_1(t)=t^2+it$ (and that is the different path) can I prove this statement is false like that?

Comment: What is the blurry symbol between "C" and "Re"?

Comment: Maybe i couldnt write exactly. I wrote this in word. I mean this is the integral on the contour C. Blurry symbol doesnt mean anything.

Comment: What about ancient Egyptian parentheses "〖〗"?  Do they mean anything?  Anyway, please fix your question by using MathJax.   https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference

Comment: Sorry for my bad writing :( i am new at here i m trying to learn. It is just parentheses doesnt mean anything. And thanks for the information about MathJax

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To prove the statement false you only need to find two different contours that given different values for the integral.

Consider $ \gamma_1 $ as the path from $ 0 $ to $ 1 + i $ that travels along the real axis to $ 1 $ and then parallel to the imaginary axis to $ 1 + i $.  Along the first leg, let $ z=x $ so that $ \Re z $ is simply $ x $ and along the second leg let $z = 1 +iy $ so that $ \Re z = 1 $

$$ \int_{\gamma_1} z dz = \int_0^1 x \cdot \frac{d}{dx} (x +i0)   dx + \int_0^1  1\cdot \frac{d}{dy} ( 1 + iy)  dy  = \frac{1}{2} + i. $$

Then repeat with contour $ \gamma_2 $, first along the imaginary axis, then the real axis.  The calulcation is very similar, and along the first leg set $ z = iy $ so that $\Re z = 0$, along the second set $z = x + i$ so that $\Re z = x $,
$$ \int_{\gamma_2} z dx = \int_0^1 0 \cdot \frac{d}{dy}(0 + iy) dy  + \int_0^1 x \cdot \frac{d}{dx}(x+i) dx = \frac{1}{2} $$

Because the two answers are different, the statement is false.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. I understood generally but i have some questions i would be very thankful if you help me. My questions are about ==> z=x, z=1+iy and z=iy, and z=x+i        why we choose like this

Comment: You will find that almost any two distinct paths give different answers.  Only functions that are analytic in a region containing both contours have the same integral between two points regardless of which contour is followed.  The function $f(z) = \Re z$ is not analytic (it fails to satisfy the Cauchy Riemann equations).  So the choice here is arbitrary, but any similar pair of paths would work as well.  For example, choose $ \gamma(t) = t^m + t^n $, where $m, n > 0$.  Work through the integration and you'll find that the results is different for different choices of $m$ and $n$.

Comment: Thank you very much, i understood completely.